# PHP Conditional Date Dropdown

Tags: php, date

I have a html select dropdown that is being generated based on some logic. Starting from the year I provide to it, it creates the given year + the next year and breaks them down into each month.

[image]

I passed `2016` to my function and it generated 12 months for 2016 and then 12 months for 2017. The Value of these inputs are the last date in each of the months. Jan = `01/31/2016`, Feb = `02/29/2016` and so on.

There is a piece of logic in place that says if today's date is the 18th of the month or greater, the month cannot be selected. Basically the 18th of every month is a cutoff date to have a project submitted by.

Here is where I need some help. And additional piece of logic needs to be added where you can never select the current month we are in.

Example: Today is Jan 14th, the soonest option I should be able to pick is February 2016 (cant pick current month). However, if today was Jan 18th - Jan31, it has passed the 18th cutoff and the soonest month I should be able to pick from is March 2016.

```
function createYearSelect($from, $preSel, $intake)
{

// for each year from the one specified to the one after current
foreach (range($from, date('Y') + 1) as $year) {

    // today
    $today = strtotime("now");

    // open optgroup for year
    $result .= "<optgroup label=\"$year\">";

    // foreach month
    foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {

        // timestamp of first day
        $time = strtotime("$year-$month-01");
        $now  = strtotime("now");

        // timestamp of cutoff date
        $cutoff = strtotime("$year-$month-18");

        // Did the cutoff date pass?
        if ($today > $cutoff) {
            $dis = 'disabled="disabled"';
        } else {
            $dis = '';
        }

        // Set our default to the month/year we are currently in
        if (date("m/Y", $time) == date("m/Y", $now)) {
            $sel = 'selected="selected"';
        } else {
            $sel = '';
        }

        // If we need to pre-select something such as "Edit Mode"
        if ($preSel) {
            if (date("m/Y", $time) == date("m/Y", strtotime($preSel))) {
                $sel = 'selected="selected"';
            } else {
                $sel = '';
            }
        }

        // If intake mode, we disable options that have passed a set date, otherwise its open.
        if ($intake) {
            $result .= "<option value=\"" . date("m/t/Y", $time) . "\" " . $dis . $sel . ">" . date("F Y", $time) . ($dis ? ' (Exceeded Cutoff)' : '') . "</option>";
        } else {
            $result .= "<option value=\"" . date("m/t/Y", $time) . "\" " . $sel . ">" . date("F Y", $time) . "</option>";
        }
    }

    // close optgroup for year
    $result .= "</optgroup>";
}
return $result;
}
```

Here is the code and output it currently provides:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71f5b5b1fcd34c018344b9acbe302f19ce94a45c

My end goal is to not allow them to pick the current month we are in and if we are past the 18th in the current month, the soonest available will be 2 months out.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you open to exploring DateTime, DateInterval, DatePeriod, etc. classes?  If you are doing anything but basic data manipulations in PHP, you should be familiar with these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Haven't tested, but hope it leads in the right direction.

```
if (date("m/Y", $time) == date("m/Y", $now) && date("d",$now) < 18) {
            $sel = 'selected="selected"';
} else if (date("m/Y", $time) == date("m/Y", strtotime("+1 month")) && date("d",$now) >= 18) {
            $sel = 'selected="selected"';
        } else { 
            $sel = '';
        }
```